# How to show only Next and Previous Buttons WordPress wp_link_pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've been trying to resolve this issue. what i'm trying is to show Next and previous button only.
Till yet i got

```
 <?php $args = array(
                            'before'           => '<div class="single-prev-next">',
                            'after'            => '</div>',
                            'link_before'      => '',
                            'link_after'       => '',
                            'next_or_number'   => 'next',
                            'nextpagelink'     => __('<div class="next">Next</div>'),
                            'previouspagelink' => __('<div class="prev">Prvious</div>'),
                            'pagelink'         => '%',
                            'more_file'        => '',
                            'echo'             => 1 ); ?>

                            <?php wp_link_pages( $args ); ?>
```

Its showing pages with numbers.
Here is output that i got.
[image: Output]

But i want it to be like this one.
[image]

I don't want Post's link i want post's child page link.
I'm using multiple pages in single post.
i'm using page break
 nextpage comment Function

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like this:

```
 <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't want Post's link i want post's child page link. I'm using multiple pages in single post. i'm using page break Function.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can use the [post_nav_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/posts_nav_link) function to show the previous / next link, or you can use them alone:

[next_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) or [previous_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)

The last to has the `get_*` version of it, to not show the link, just return.

Comment: The functions are named `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` (posts, not post).

Comment: Exactly! it is used to change post not child page of post.

Comment: I don't want Post's link i want post's child page link. I'm using multiple pages in single post. i'm using page break Function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to give Previous Next buttons in Wordpress Post

```
function genesis_page_numbers() {
$args = array(
                        'before'           => '<div class="single-prev-next">',
                        'after'            => '</div>',
                        'link_before'      => '',
                        'link_after'       => '',
                        'next_or_number'   => 'next',
                        'nextpagelink'     => __('<div class="int_next">Next</div>'),
                        'previouspagelink' => __('<div class="int_prev">Previous</div>'),
                        'pagelink'         => '%',
                        'more_file'        => '',
                        'echo'             => 1 ); 
wp_link_pages( $args ); 
}
add_action('genesis_entry_header','genesis_page_numbers');
```

Paste the above code in funtions.php and you are good to go.

Also if you want to remove the default pagination use this code:

```
  remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content_nav', 12);
```